# Apply generics on Angular providers

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

Is it possible to declare `membervar` of class `Parent` generic instead of type `any` without loosing the flexibility to exchange provider class? Especially I don't want to modify each component that depends on class `Parent`, if the type (`<T>`) changes, that means if class `ChildB` implements a different type of class `Parent` as class ChildA.

```
export abstract class Parent {
  membervar: any;
}
export class ChildA extends Parent {
  constructor() {       
    super();
    this.membervar = ObjectA();
  }
}
export class ChildB extends Parent {
  constructor() {       
    super();
    this.membervar = ObjectB();
  }
}
```

In my app.module.ts I can switch the provider among the child classes via:

```
...
providers: [ { provide: Parent, useClass: ChildA } ]
...
```

And there exists some components that depend on the structure above:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private aService: Parent) {

  }
}
export class SomeOtherComponent...
  constructor(private aService: Parent)...
```

Comment: `export abstract class Parent<T> {
  membervar: T;
}` then you have a generic, and can use `class ChildB extends Parent<typeof ObjectB>`

Comment: @Zokki, thats right, but how about  `SomeComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

```ts
class GenericComp<T> {
    constructor(protected genericService: T) {}
}

class TestComp extends GenericComp<ApiService> {
    testFn() {
        // this.genericService -> is of type ApiService
    }
}
```

If you want to have the parent just use the Class as Param

```ts
class TestComp extends GenericComp<TestComp> {
    testFn() {
        // this.genericService -> is of type TestComp
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get your idea. Can you keep closer to the structure of the start post? For instance `class TestComp extends GenericComp<ChildA>` destroys the flexibility, because I have to modify it, when switching to ChildB.